# Does libcurl abort download if file size exceeds Content-Length?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have a web application where user can post url to have his file downloaded. I'm using libcurl and I'm checking response Content-Length to enforce file size limit. I'm worried that some carried away server will continue uploading and will eventually fill up all available space and choke my server. Will libcurl abort downloading file if it's size is greater than Content-Length?

Comment: You could whip up a simple test case and try it yourself... A script which outputs 100k, and a download script which expects only 50k.

Comment: @MarcB okay I did it and it stopped on Content-Length. So far so good. But I would really appreciate an authoritative answer. Like with link to source where it checks for file size. Because may be presence of some other headers can change something (everything), you know.

Comment: @MarcB besides I don't know may be it was my test server (Webrick) who stopped streaming because I set Content-Length header less than file size. And not libcurl stopped receiving. How should I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will (mostly). As the Content-Length field (when used) is how HTTP is used to tell the size of the body of this particular response. An HTTP client cannot read any further than so, as the connection will be kept open and re-used for the next request.

This is basic HTTP 1.1 functionality and you can find the details in [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) and if you want to read curl code, check out the lib/http.c source code for the Content-Length header matching and parsing and then further how the 'maxdownload' field is used in lib/transfer.c etc.